# page onload alerts

Tags: javascript

i want to show an alerts when a page loads .but i wat it to show only once in a session so that the users does not get disturbed.
please help me with some javascript codes.

in hope robin
.

Comment: Are you using any JavaScript framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the javascript code [link](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/alertmsg.shtml) alert onload and only once per browser session

Answer (score 2):

You can use [cookie](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) with short expiration date, e.g. 1 day.